# Multiplying two numbers outside main() function yields unknown result

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a function that calculates Least Common Multiple, but when it multiplies two variables (301337, 307829), the program can't multiply the two numbers inside lcm function for some reason. I have tried changing type to long long but that made no difference. When I multiplied 2 variables inside the main function, it worked perfect. Thank you.

```
int lcm(int a, int b)
{
    int l = a * b;
    cout << l << endl; // Displays -12790139
    int g = gcd(a, b);
    cout << g << endl; // works correct
    return l/g;
}

int main() {
    cout << lcm(301337, 307829) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `long long` will work as long as the result isn't cut off before it's even used (i.e., you don't multiply two `int`s and then convert the result to a `long long`).

Comment: @chris I should have noticed that. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

i guess this will work

```
int lcm(int a, int b)
{
unsigned long long int l = a * b;
cout << l << endl; // Displays 18446744071980538477
int g = gcd(a, b);
cout << g << endl; // works correct
return l/g;
}

int main() {
cout << lcm(301337, 307829) << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Parameters of lcm also have to be long long.

Answer (score 0):

`int l = a * b;` is going out of range. use `long long` instead.
if you don't want to change **a** and **b**, only **l**, then use it like this:

```
long long l =(long long)a * b;
```

Comment: On many platforms, `long` and `int` are the same size.  `long long` would be a better choice.

Comment: I see, thnks, @RichieHindle

Answer (score 0):

301337 * 307829 = 92760267373 , Overflow !! it does not fit in an Integer which can handle only numbers in the intervalle ]-2^32,2^32[ .
use long long instead or unsigned long long instead.